# Retrofit - onFailure on non-empty body, onResponse on empty body

Tags: android, kotlin

My GET request doesn't work properly in Android Studio. I tried to put the same requests in Postman and in result I always got response code 200 with correct body. However, using Retrofit I get onResponse (200 code) when response body is empty (there is no data) and onFailure when response body is not empty (there are some reservations).

EDIT: I have just noticed such error in logs: `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 22 path $[0].reservationDate`

EDIT2: JSON RESPONSE

```
[
    {
        "reservationDate": "2019-10-30",
        "id": "4"
    }
]
```

API Service:

```
    @Headers("Authorization: Bearer ...")
    @GET("reservations")
    fun getSchedule(@Query("id") id: Int,
                    @Query("reservationDate") reservationDate: LocalDate

    ):  Call<List<ScheduleModel>>


    companion object {
        fun create(): ScheduleService{

            var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("myUrl")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

            return retrofit.create(ScheduleService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

```
data class ScheduleModel(
    val id: Int,
    val reservationDate: LocalDate
)
```

```
fun getReservations() {
        var service = ScheduleService.create()
        var localdate = LocalDate.of(2019,10,30)

        var call = service.getSchedule(4, localdate)

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<ScheduleModel>> {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<ScheduleModel>>, response: Response<List<ScheduleModel>>) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "It's ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ScheduleModel>>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Show your JSON response

Comment: Please implement null check in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `id` and `reservationDate` in response is a `String` but you try to parse it as `Int` and `LocalDate`. Change the types and it's gonna be work.